# How to get remote host DNS address from a super-slim host (docker) without ping or bind-utils?

Tags: docker, host-name-resolution

How do I get a remote host IP address if I don't have ping, and don't have any bind utilities like dig, nslookup, etc?

I need an answer that does not include 'install X' or 'use sidecar container'. I am looking for something that relies on nothing more than bash and the basic shell commands.

Comment: got the host command?

Comment: The `host` command from ISC is exactly the sort of _BIND utility_ that the questioner said that xe does not have.  (Of course there are the alternative `host` commands from KnotDNS or from the djbwares toolset, so it isn't _solely_ a BIND utility.  (-:)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `getent`:

```
$ getent hosts unix.stackexchange.com
151.101.193.69    unix.stackexchange.com  unix.stackexchange.com
```

Answer (score 1):

On a "modern" system, you can use `systemd-resolve`.

From its man page:

> systemd-resolve may be used to resolve domain names, IPv4 and IPv6
>   addresses, DNS resource records and services with the
>   systemd-resolved.service(8) resolver service. By
>          default, the specified list of parameters will be resolved as hostnames, retrieving their IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. If the parameters
>   specified are formatted as IPv4 or
>          IPv6 operation the reverse operation is done, and a hostname is retrieved for the specified addresses.

It will do DNS, whereas getent, depending on `nsswitch.conf` may not even do DNS queries.
You can also pass a `--type` option to have access to any kind of DNS record type.

Comment: Nice and informative. But docker images dont package systemd as there is no run-level within the image, as well as quite a few oher missing tings that systemd requires.